# screen.width and screen.height show dimensions of wrong screen

Tags: javascript

I am using `screen.width` and `screen.height` to size a canvas element for showing in full screen. However I am developing and running on one screen (1080x1920), and displaying/showing the browser on another screen (2560 x 1600), which makes it so that the canvas is sized according to the screen I am developing on (1080x1920). That is `screen.width = 1080` (adjusted for devicePixelRatio) and the same for `screen.height`.

Is this intentional behavior, or is there some way of fixing this?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to size the canvas based on the window size rather than the screen size?

Comment: No, because the size of the window is only the size of the browser, not the whole screen, and when it goes full screen, it is not the correct size

Comment: So then request fullscreen and then set the height

Comment: You've got a point, thanks!